# error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "script"

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I have a route

```
app.get('/chats/:user_id', async (req, res) => {
    const user_id = req.params.user_id;
    const room = new Room(user_id);
    const userRooms = (await db.query(room.getUserRooms())).rows;
    console.log(userRooms);
    res.render('index', { rooms: userRooms });
});
```

In it I request user chats.

```
class Room {
    constructor(id) {
        this.user_id = id;
    }

    getUserRooms() {
        const sql = `SELECT R.CHAT_ID, R.RECEIVER, R.SENDER FROM CHATS AS R WHERE R.RECEIVER = ${this.user_id} OR R.SENDER = ${this.user_id}`;
        return sql;
    }
}

module.exports = Room;
```

I get an error:

> (node:6944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "script"
>       at Connection.parseE (C:\Users\User\Documents\Realtime-Chat-App-With-Rooms\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:604:11)
>       at Connection.parseMessage (C:\Users\User\Documents\Realtime-Chat-App-With-Rooms\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:401:19)
>       at TLSSocket. (C:\Users\User\Documents\Realtime-Chat-App-With-Rooms\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:121:22)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
>       at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
>       at TLSWrap.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
>   (node:6944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 10)

I can’t understand why this error occurs.

Where did I make a mistake?

I did as they asked me `const userRooms = await db.query(room.getUserRooms())`

```
Result {
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 2,
  oid: null,
  rows:
   [ { chat_id: 1, receiver: 51, sender: 71 },
     { chat_id: 2, receiver: 71, sender: 51 } ],
  fields:
   [ Field {
       name: 'chat_id',
       tableID: 42149012,
       columnID: 1,
       dataTypeID: 23,
       dataTypeSize: 4,
       dataTypeModifier: -1,
       format: 'text' },
     Field {
       name: 'receiver',
       tableID: 42149012,
       columnID: 2,
       dataTypeID: 23,
       dataTypeSize: 4,
       dataTypeModifier: -1,
       format: 'text' },
     Field {
       name: 'sender',
       tableID: 42149012,
       columnID: 3,
       dataTypeID: 23,
       dataTypeSize: 4,
       dataTypeModifier: -1,
       format: 'text' } ],
  _parsers:
   [ [Function: parseInteger],
     [Function: parseInteger],
     [Function: parseInteger] ],
  _types:
   TypeOverrides {
     _types:
      { getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
        setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
        arrayParser: [Object],
        builtins: [Object] },
     text: {},
     binary: {} },
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false }
```

```
[ { chat_id: 1, receiver: 51, sender: 71 },
  { chat_id: 2, receiver: 71, sender: 51 } ]
```

Comment: What is `table "script"`?

Comment: I do not have such a table and I do not spend any work with it

Comment: I have FROM `SELECT R.CHAT_ID, R.RECEIVER, R.SENDER FROM CHATS AS ...`

Comment: try to wrap up your query with the `try catch`

Comment: It didn’t help me.

Comment: Table alias `R` for `CHATS`?!? Why not `C`, to spare us some confusion...

Comment: @jarlh the table used to be called rooms, this is my flaw

Comment: Actually you can avoid using any alias in that query. `SELECT CHAT_ID, RECEIVER, SENDER FROM CHATS WHERE RECEIVER = ${this.user_id} OR SENDER = ${this.user_id}`

Comment: Could You log the `user_id` vairable ? I just guess that it doesn't contain just Id, because SQL says, that You are using some table that is not in the FROM.

Comment: Do this, please `const userRooms = await db.query(room.getUserRooms())` and then let us no what are you getting in the console if there are no errors.

Comment: @daniyal-lukmanov I did as you asked me

Comment: And now, please try to `console.log(userRooms.rows)`

Comment: @daniyal-lukmanov The error remains, the error disappears when I clean the `res.render('index', { rooms: userRooms });`

Comment: I believe that problem is in your `(await db.query(room.getUserRooms())).rows`. You are trying to get rows before you get result from your query.

Comment: @daniyal-lukmanov If i do so `const userRooms = await db.query(room.getUserRooms())`  or `const userRooms = (await db.query(room.getUserRooms())).rows;` I get the same result

Comment: But as we see in your updated question there are `rows` logged in the console

Comment: This looks like the error originates from a different piece of code altogether than the one you are showing.